# Rails validation on previous record less than an hour old

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Beginner question:

```
class Report < ApplicationRecord
  validates :message, presence: true
  validates :user_has_waited_an_hour, on: :create

  def user_has_waited_an_hour
    if Report.exists?(created_by: self.created_by, created_at: 1.hour.ago..DateTime.now)
        errors.add(:message, "If you wanted to add some more info you're going to have to wait for an hour.")
    end
  end
end
```

But it's giving me this error, which I know to be due to the definition, because without it there is no error:

```
ArgumentError (You need to supply at least one validation):

app/models/report.rb:3:in `<class:Report>'
app/models/report.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/reports_controller.rb:26:in `new'
```

Comment: You should add the error to :base as it's not tied to a specific attribute. And you should also read up on DateTime.current vs .now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a custom validation method you need to use `validate` as opposed to `validates`:

```
class Report < ApplicationRecord
  validates :message, presence: true
  validate :user_has_waited_an_hour, on: :create

  def user_has_waited_an_hour
    if Report.exists?(created_by: self.created_by, created_at: 1.hour.ago..DateTime.now)
        errors.add(:message, "If you wanted to add some more info you're going to have to wait for an hour.")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Ah, proper english.  I am Indubitably much obliged.